# Display Camera Input in / onto QT application HOWTO / Way to go

Tags: c++, qt, camera, framebuffer, v4l

I am working on the implementation of a QT application on an Embedded Linux Display with CAN Bus Interface and PAl Camera Interface. The overall aim is to visualize then Sensor Data of the machine (driving speed km/h etc.) with modern looking Gauges and also to show the CAMERA input in the lower half of the Display. It does not matter whether the CAMERA input rectangle is a GUI Widget (having all features of the QT framework) or whether it is just independently displayed (overlayed pixelwise I mean) onto the screen.

Environment:

- Software: Linux 4.1.15,
- Available QT platform plugins: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, wayland-egl, wayland.
- Camera: /dev/video0 /dev/video1 Video4Linux Devices, Driver mxc_v4l2.
- Hardware is Freescale / NXP, i.MX6 Solo / Quad, ARM Cortex-A9, 800 MHz (Solo) / 1000 MHz (Quad).

Basic display of the camera input onto the screen works fine using Framebuffer output device /dev/fb0.

What is the most easiest way to display a Camera Input then within or onto a QT application? Can you advise/ recommend a way to go?